# repeating user-sp written in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a t-sql user-defined-sp (call it `sp1`) which gets userId as param and return

I want to create a new user-defined-sp (call it `sp2`) that gets a list of userIds.

sp2 executes sp1 for each userId and union all output to one big output.

Each set of outputs for userId=a will be consecutive in the big table

i.e. the big table can look like:

```
a  result1,1 
a  result1,2
a  result1,3
b  result2,1
b  result2,1
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Can you change sp1 to be a user defined function?

Comment: It is user defined. My bad for not clarifying

Comment: Function or procedure sorry? They are 2 different things in SQL Server? If function, look at my answer

Comment: sp1 and sp2 are both user-defined-procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the main stored proc (sp2), you can create a table variable, and populate it with the data, then select all from that table variable.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @loop_tbl TABLE (ID int identity(1,1), UserID int)
DECLARE @return_tbl TABLE (column_a varchar(1), column_result varchar(20), column_int int)
DECLARE @min int, @max int

INSERT INTO @loop_tbl(UserID) SELECT UserID FROM Users
SELECT @min=MIN(ID), @max=MAX(ID) FROM @loop_tbl

WHILE @min <= @max
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @return_tbl (column_a, column_result, column_int)
    EXEC sp1 @userid=(SELECT UserID FROM @loop_tbl WHERE ID=@min)
    --Proc must return a data set using SELECT with the proper columns in the proper order

    SET @min=@min+1
END

SELECT * FROM @return_tbl
```

The only thing to watch out for is that `INSERT EXEC` will fail if sp2 is nested inside of another stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   * -- change this
FROM
  ListOfIds T
  CROSS APPLY
  dbo.UDFT1 (T.@userid) T1
```

This assumes

- the list of Ids is already in a table (`ListOfIds` here)
- T1 is actually a UDF, not a stored procedure